# Why is the obj emailIntent null?

Tags: android

In the function SetIntent, I have  initialized the object inputIntent, both  inputIntent and emailIntent are the same pointer.
Why is the obj emailIntent null and display "Error"?

```
Intent emailIntent=null;        
Utility.SetIntent(getApplicationContext(),emailIntent, myindex);
if (emailIntent==null){
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error" ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}   


public static final String MyIntent=Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE;
public static final String MySetType="image/*"; 

public static void SetIntent(Context mycontext, Intent inputIntent, int index) {
    inputIntent = new Intent(MyIntent);
    inputIntent.setType(MySetType);
    PackageManager pm = mycontext.getPackageManager();
    List<ResolveInfo> emailers = pm.queryIntentActivities(inputIntent, 0);
    int dbIndex=index-1;
    if (
         ((dbIndex)<= (emailers.size()-1))
         && 
         ((dbIndex)>=0) 
        )
    {
        ResolveInfo r = emailers.get(dbIndex);
        inputIntent.setClassName(r.activityInfo.packageName, r.activityInfo.name);
        Toast.makeText(mycontext,r.activityInfo.packageName+"  "+r.activityInfo.name ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    }
```

Comment: Well, you're setting it to null, right? `emailIntent=null;` ?

Comment: show your full code and log,please

Comment: I have to set emailIntent=null first, if not, I will get the error 
The local variable emailIntent may not have been initialized ! But I have invoke the function Utility.SetIntent to  initialize emailIntent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

return modified intent object from
Utility.SetIntent(getApplicationContext(),emailIntent, myindex) method. How are you expecting to change the emailIntent inside Utility class?
There are no pointers in java.

So, your method in Utility has to be:

public static Intent SetIntent(Context, Intent, int) {
// your code goes here
// your code goes here
}

emailIntent = Utility.SetIntent(getApplicationContext(),emailIntent, myindex);

And, as the logic is considered, you need not pass intent to setIntent method. Create a local intent object in SetIntent method and return the same.

**NOTE:**
Please follow naming conventions. SetIntent() should be setIntent().